# What kind of flower is this?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image: flower]

What kind of flower is this? Saw it online while looking up photos for a biology project and now I'm curious as to what kind it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's a Dahlia, a pom pom variety called York and Lancaster, which refers to the random red and white petals - this variety can produce all white, all red or random mixed red and white, like your example http://plantlust.com/plants/36392/dahlia-york-and-lancaster/